# Restart one script in other script in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I restart one script in other script?
I've tried this, but it doesn't working

```
Ball.Start();
```

Comment: Have you tried `Ball.Reset()`? According to the docs [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html): Start is called exactly once in the lifetime of the script. Is the problem that you've stopped the script, but cannot start it once again?

Comment: According to [Unity Answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/704368/how-to-restartrerun-a-script.html) you can restart the script by using `SetActive` to enable/disable and implement the `OnEnabled` method.

Comment: What do you expect a "restart" to do? If you make `Start` a public function, you can call it from other scripts (as long as you have an object to call it on). If you're seeing errors in your console window, what are they? If not, what's happening or not happening, and how does that differ from what you expect?

Comment: @ShawnicHedgehog It doesn't work too. And yes, Start()called exactly once in the lifetime of the script and therefore I want to start this script again. I have one script for making levels of Arkanoid, and I want to reset life of ball.

Comment: @JohnOdom, can I use it for scripts, but it doesn't work, I wonder it is for GameObjects.

Comment: @rutter, I cant to make public method Start(), because it could be static for call from other script and script of ball, never start up when I change it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Unity manual:

```
Like the Awake function, Start is called exactly once in the lifetime of the script.
```

What you can do is this:

```
void Start()
{
   Init();
}

public void Init()
{
   // Some logic here
}
```

Then you can just call `Init()` from where ever you want.

If you're referring to completely reset a MonoBehaviour, you could remove/add it:

```
Destroy(gameObject.GetComponent<MyMonoBehaviour>());
gameObject.AddComponent<MyMonoBehaviour>();
```